# Creating a rollover with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, rollover

I've read a TON of question and answers about rollovers using PHP and Javascript and can't figure out why this isn't working. So I have this PHP code:

```
$rollover = '$("#' . $godName . '").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#' . $godName . '").attr("src","img/gods/god_cards/dark/' . $godImage . '2.png");
});
$("#' . $godName . '").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#' . $godName . '").attr("src","img/gods/god_cards/' . $godImage . '.png");
});';
```

`$godName` and `$godImage` are variables retrieved through a query to a database. I wanted to use this code to cut down on the amount I'd have to write to create a rollover for over 50 images, so basically it would create a function for every image retrieved in the query. Then I wanted to stick it in a javascript tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <?php echo $rollover; ?>
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. And I've tried doing it with and without the echo and no version of whatever I've found on here or anywhere else works. When I echo it out as just text it looks fine, it spits out what it should so I'm not sure why the javascript just doesn't seem to be accepting the php. Any help?

Comment: Try saving the resulting page source and trying that directly, to cut PHP out of the equation.

Comment: You can use a div with a background and then, when the mouse is over, the background changes. That is a lot easier.

Comment: It would be a lot easier just to use a div, to begin with. The problem is that I want to do this rollover effect with multiple images. A LOT of images. The reason why I'm trying to do it this way is so I won't have to write a separate rollover for each image 50 times over. Basically each image has its own special rollover image.

Answer (score 2):

Do you check if the HTML Dom is ready? You are using jQuery, so you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
      <?php echo $rollover; ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried and unfortunately that doesn't work either